# What does "assume by contradiction that a<=-2" mean?

Tags: mathematics

I want to prove the following statement.

> If a+2>0, then a>-2.

What does "assume by contradiction that a<=-2" mean?

Comment: It means this is going to be a proof by contradiction. That means  assume something that's known to be false and show how that isn't right and therefore the opposite must be true.

Comment: There is a stack exchange board for math questions (at any level of expertise), which this is: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof by contradiction depends on the law of the excluded middle. The law of the excluded middle, in this situation, claims that either a > -2 is true OR else a <= -2 is true.

Thus, an "assumption by contradiction" is technically a [theorem in propositional logic that is not susceptible of proof or disproof](https://www.crosswordsolver.com/clue/A-PROPOSITION-THAT-IS-NOT-SUSCEPTIBLE-OF-PROOF-OR-DISPROOF).

Comment: You are right that this is about the Law of the Excluded Middle, but I would revise your second sentence to say: "Either a > -2 is true, or else a <= -2 is true."  Given the "if ... then ..." claim in OP, it looks like their goal is to prove that, under some hypotheses, a>-2 is true. One way to show this is to assume the *logical negation* of that, namely that a is NOT less than -2, i.e. a >= -2.

Comment: Mathematicians who reject proof by contradiction don’t tend to get very far.

Comment: @gnasher729 But if they did, ...  ;)